# JavaScript to get array of keys from array of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this array, each object in the array has one key only:

```
[{ "hello": "value1" }, { "there": "value2" }, { "everybody": "value3" }]
```

I want to extract all the keys into an array such that the result I want is:

```
["hello", "there", "everybody"]
```

What's a succinct way of doing this in Lodash or vanilla JavaScript (preferably ES6)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combine to a single object using [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), and retrieve the keys from the object using [Object#keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
const arr = [{ "hello": "value1" }, { "there": "value2" }, { "everybody": "value3" }];

const keys = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...arr));

console.log(keys);
```

And the ES5 version using lodash's [`_.assign()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assign) with [`_.spread()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#spread) to combine to a single object, and [`_.keys()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#keys) to get the keys:

```js
var arr = [{ "hello": "value1" }, { "there": "value2" }, { "everybody": "value3" }];

var keys = _.keys(_.spread(_.assign)(arr))

console.log(keys);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Array#map` together with `Object.keys`.

```js
let arr = [{ "hello": "value1" }, { "there": "value2" }, { "everybody": "value3" }];

let keys = [].concat(...arr.map(Object.keys));

console.log(keys);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use array [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combining with object [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
const array = [{ "hello": "value1" }, { "there": "value2" }, { "everybody": "value3" }];

const result = array.map((el) => Object.keys(el)[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x = [{ "hello": "value1" }, { "there": "value2" }, { "everybody": "value3" }];

console.log(x.map(function(obj){return Object.keys(obj)[0]}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using lodash's [**flatMap**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatMap):

```
let result = _.flatMap(data, _.keys);
```

Answer (score 1):

A native ES5 solution for this that preserves duplicate keys would be:

```
var objects = [{ "hello": "value1" }, { "there": "value2" }, { "everybody": "value3" }];
var keys = [];
for (var obj in objets) {
    keys.push(Object.keys(obj)[0]);
}
```